# Problem with FilesMatch not matching correctly

Tags: apache2, struts

We are having an issue with `FilesMatch`, it does not seem to be matching some file types. We are using the `FilesMatch` directive to allow me to add custom headers using `mod_headers`, config file details snippit below:

```
<FilesMatch  \.(list|dept|png|html|htm)>
Header set Last-Modified  "Mon, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
Header set Expires "Mon, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

We are using `mod_jk` to pass connections to Tomcat and the Struts to rename the files to .dept & .list ,etc.

The issue appears to be with matching the `text/html` , as files that are being served as files with `.png` (used in the regex match for sanity check) are matching fine.

Is there a specific file extension that I should be trying to match in Apache when the files are being renamed with Struts?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue by using LocationMatch

```
<LocationMatch "\.(html|htm|shtml|shtm|txt|text)$" >
Header set Custom-Header1
....
</LocationMatch>
```